# How to allow user to make permanent changes to log levels?

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, log4j2

I have a Spring Boot application that uses log4j2 for logging. I have a need to adjust the logging level at run time and I have done that with a simple RESTful interface that accepts a logger name and the level it needs to be set at. I also need to be able to make permanent changes to the logging level (on just certain loggers).

a) Is there a way to persist my changes back to the log4j config file so that the next time the application is brought up, the log levels are where they had been left at, on the previous run?

b) Is there a way to read the list of loggers listed in the config file?

Thank you

Comment: You'd need to write them out to persistent storage of some sort, such as a database.

Comment: Your config is usually in your war/ear file so you cannot write to it. The container won't let you. So as @chrylis says you need to store it in persistent store that is normally accessible to containerized applications.

Answer (score 1):

a) If you have a config file, every time the server starts it will be used to configure log4j2. You could create a new config file (outside the container) and use it to configure log4j2 when the server starts:

```
    File file = new File("/config/new/log4j2.xml");             
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);     
    ctx.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Or just store the new info and modify log4j programatically

b) Try this:

```
public Collection<Logger> getLoggers()
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html#getLoggers()

Here's a code example (executed at the application startup):

```
    File file = new File(log4jConfigFilePath);      
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ctx.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());

    Collection<org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger> collection = ctx.getLoggers();     
    System.out.println(collection.size()); // returns 0 (No loggers instantiated)

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogger");

    collection = ctx.getLoggers();      
    System.out.println(collection.size()); // returns 1 (myLogger instantiated)
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco.  My log4j2 config file is outside the container. Following the steps you indicated, I didn't get back the list of loggers listed/configured in the config file. If I get past that hurdle and I allow for the logger levels to be changed programmatically, is there a way to store/persist the change back to the config file? Thanks

Comment: getLoggers() returns the the current loggers, and each instance should belong to one of your loggers listed in the config file. Of course if you didn't create any instance with LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName) it will return null.  Sadly there isn't a way to persist changes made programatically using the log4j2 API. The only way to persist it would be creating a new config file (or updating the current one) using the java's file I/O API

Comment: getLoggers() is not returning the loggers in the config file. Would I have to rely on regular file I/O and string parsing to read/parse and figure that out? Thanks

Comment: getLogger() returns the loggers that are already in use in your application. If you define a logger in the config file but it hasn't been instantiated by your app the method does not return it. It makes sense, why would you change programmatically the configuration of a logger that is not in use in your application? Anyway, yes, you should relay on regular File I/O to persist the changes but notice that log4j config files are written in XML, JSON, YAML, or properties format so you have tools to parse and modify it easily (not need of String parsing).

Comment: The reason was to find out what the initial loggers (lets say critical components) were to set to and present that in the UI. And ultimately since I am looking to persist the changes, I need to know what they are, the next time the application comes up. But I do see your point.
The list of loggers that I get from the LoggerContext is the same same whether I setConfigLocation() or not. It doesn't seem to be doing anything. I am calling it just the way you had indicated.